# How to await inside forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need get Firestore document in forEach loop. But I get error: `'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules`

How to get document in forEach loop?

```
querySnapshot.forEach(queryDocumentSnapshot => {
  const doc = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('Collection')
    .doc(queryDocumentSnapshot.id)
    .get();
 
  if (doc.id) {
   // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: @tomdaly Thanks for reply! No it not answer. If I use `for (const queryDocumentSnapshot of querySnapshot) {` it give error: `Type 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`